# How to compile Dart server into Javascript and run with NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, server, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to run my Dart server in Firebase Cloud functions, but it does not support Dart Runtime, so I thought that maybe it is possible to compile it to JS and run it there with NodeJS. I did the test on my local machine with this simple code:

```
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  print("Hello world once");
  var app = Router();

  app.get('/hello', (Request request) {
    return Response.ok('hello-world');
  });

  app.get('/user/<user>', (Request request, String user) {
    return Response.ok('hello $user');
  });

  var server = await io.serve(app, 'localhost', 8080);
  print("Hello worl 2");
}
```

If I run: `dart main.dart` it prints

```
Hello world once
Hello worl 2
```

And if I got to `http://localhost:8080/hello`, I get `hello-world`.

However, if I run:  `dart compile js main.dart` and run `node out.js`, it only prints

```
Hello world once
```

And the server is not responding.

I read some people say it is not possible to use `dart.io` in compiled to JS code, but I am not sure about the veracity of such and if even if it's true, why ? Is there a workaround ? My frontend is in `Flutter` and I don't wanna write my backend code with a different language.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFY3he2hcXM

Comment: I checked your link but this seems to not work on Dart 2 and 3 anymore

Comment: Have you seen this article - [Writing Cloud Functions In Dart](https://medium.com/icnh/writing-cloud-functions-in-dart-b7e62192b3bc)?

Comment: Outdated Not working on dart 3

Comment: If the aim is to use Dart as serverless on the Google Cloud Platform, how about using [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run) which supports Dart, combined with Firebase Hosting as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run ?

Comment: You need to containerize your dart code using docker then your code can now run on cloud functions. Read this documentation. https://dart.dev/server/google-cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This incompatibility arises because *dart:io* provides access to the underlying system's resources, which is not allowed in managed serverless services like Cloud Functions.
As has already been written by [@Boaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889273/boaz), Cloud Run can be your solution since you can containerise your code which will allow access to the OS system.